# How do I use the exact color of one part, then put it on another part?

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing, color, vertex-colors

The title might be a bit confusing, buts lets say I import a 3D model and the torso is blue. how would I select that exact color and put it on the legs? Thank you.

Comment: you can take a look at the material and Ctrl C the color that is used

Answer (score 6):

**Follow this GIF if you want to assign a colour to a different object.**

Hover over the base colour selection in your object and press <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on your keyboard to copy the colour, then hover of the base colour option in your other object and press <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> to paste it.

[image]

**Please follow this GIF if you want to assign the same colour to the faces in the same object**

Select your object, press <kbd>↹ Tab</kbd> to go to *Edit mode*, create a new material, copy the colour by hovering over the base colour option and pressing <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> on your keyboard, then paste it into the new material that you created by hovering over the base colour option and pressing <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.

[image]